# Determining an estimator for two parameters in R over a sum, given binary data

Tags: r, optimization, binary-data

I have the following sum (it is a score-vector to a partial likelihood) and want to find the values for beta_0 and beta_1 for which the equation is equal to zero.

The Y_t’s {t=0,...n} are known measurements at different points in time and can only be 0 or 1 (binary data).

[image]

Here is the code I came up with so far. I tried to implement the function, which should be minimized:

```
    y = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0)

    f <- function(beta_0, beta_1){

      sum = matrix(c(0, 0), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)

      for(t in 2:length(y))
      {
        sum = sum + matrix(c(1, y[t-1]), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)  %*% c(y[t] - (exp(beta_0 + beta_1 * y[t-1])) / (1 + exp(beta_0 + beta_1 * y[t-1])))

      }

      return(sum)
    } 
    #Just making a guess:
    f(0.5,0.5)
```

There is no analytical solution for this and therefor I’d like to use R to determine both parameters (beta_0 and beta_1) given a set of binary data. To find the numerical solution,  I think some kind of iterative solution is the way to go.

So far I have looked at different optimization packages in R but couldn’t find the right one.

One of the problems I'm facing is that the result of the function is an vector and the optimization approaches I have seen so far, all just use an output of one variable.

Could you recommend a package for this problem, or any other way I could solve this? Maybe treat the Vector as one number, by adding the absolute values of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using absolute values and optim:

```
 estimate_parameter_binary_model  <- function(y = y) {

  #Function to be optimized:
  optimization_function_binary_model <- function(p = c(1,1)){ #to use the optim function, it has to be called by a vector p. Which contains: p[1] = beta_0 and p[2] = beta_1

    #p is an vector and contains both parameters
    beta_0 = p[1]
    beta_1 = p[2]

    sum = matrix(c(0, 0), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)

    for(t in 2:length(y))
    {
      sum = sum + matrix(c(1, y[t-1]), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)  %*% c(y[t] - (exp(beta_0 + beta_1 * y[t-1])) / (1 + exp(beta_0 + beta_1 * y[t-1])))

    }

    return(abs(sum[1]) + abs(sum[2])) #optim just needs one number, so we use absolute values here and add them.
  } 

  #Call optim()

  par = optim(c(0,0), optimization_function_binary_model)$par

  Solution<- list(beta_0 = par[1],beta_1 = par[2])

  return(Solution)
}
```